# retrieving the updated value of variable A on form2 closing? C#

Tags: c#, forms, variables, formclosing

This is a very simple question yet I couldn't find a solution for it (I am not a pro programmer sorry if this is primitive!). In Form1 I have a variable called "A" and it's value is 1. I send this to Form2 and change the value to 2. And on Form2 closing I need to send the updated value to Form1. This last part I don't know how to do that and I need your help. How can I retrieve the updated value of variable A on form2 closing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a value that is changed by Form2, and that value is managed by Form2, you can expose it as a property of Form2, e.g.

```
public class Form2
{
    public string MyValue
    {
        get { return myValue; }
    }
}
```

and then you can retrieve it like

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();
string theValue = f2.MyValue;
```

In general you may want to check the DialogResult returned by ShowDialog() to see if the user pressed e.g. the OK or Cancel button.  I'm not sure if you need that in this particular case.

**UPDATE**

If Form2 is not a dialog, you can instead use a callback pattern to inform Form1 that Form2 is closing to allow Form1 to retrieve any values that it needs from Form2.  Alternatively you can have the callback directly supply the value you need.

Specifically, you could pass a `Func<T>` to Form2 that points to a callback method in Form1.  Form2 would then call that `Func<T>` when it determines that it is closing.  Here, `T` represents the type of variable that you want passed back to Form1.

Here's an example that assumes `T` is a string:

```
public Form2 : Form
{
    public void MyCallback(string value) { /* Do something with value */
}

public Form1 : Form
{
    Func<string> callback;
    public Form1(Func<string> callback)     
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (callback != null) callback(myValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only applicable if form2 is a dialog.

Comment: The only problem with this is when I update my variable in Form 2, in form1 still the value is not updated.

Comment: @davenewza: The invocation example shows a dialog, true.  But the method of retrieving the value works for any form.

Comment: @davenewza: Updated to show an answer that works well when it is not a dialog.

Answer (score 2):

WinForm has an Event called `FormClosing`. Right click on the form and choose properties, on right side of IDE you will get properties. There will be an icon like "lightning" in yellow color. You will find the `FormClosing` event there. Now add the code you want when form is closing

Answer (score 2):

You could handle the the `form2.FormClosing` event on `form1`.  There you can retrieve your value `form2.B` (provided that it is publicly accessible) on `form1` as `form2` is closing.

```
form2.FormClosing += OnFormBClosing;

private void OnFormBClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    A = form2.B;
}
```

Comment: I would really like to understand the 3 downvotes here.  From the FAQ: *Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!*

Answer (score 0):

Use from closing event

```
private void Form2_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   //update 
}
```

[MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It would probably better if you can post your actual source code.

I suppose that you open Form2 from Form1, is it right? If true, I think it would be probably better to write something like this that trying to update form1 from form2 closing event.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.A = this.A; // here this = form1
if (DialogResult.OK == form2.ShowDialog())
{
    // So here, retrieve the property from form2.
    this.A = form2.A;
}
```